# Convert Datetime to PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

I have a datetime string as such `14/04/2014 4:57:16 PM` and I am using carbon datetime to work on it.

However as soon as I try to do this

```
$dt = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($encDateTime);
```

However I am getting parse errors : DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@14/04/2014 5:03:45 PM ) at position 3 (/): Unexpected character.

**Udpate :** 
I tried doing this :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $encDateTime);
dd($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

and I get the following error 
**Call to a member function format() on a non-object**

Can you please help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($encDateTime);` output?

Comment: @AmalMurali : it returns this : 14/04/2014 4:57:16 PM

Comment: @Gagan: `var_dump()` would never return that. What's the exact output?

Comment: also I might be mistaken but in your *update* you used H which signifies a 2 digit hour, instead of h - and this could result in the string not being parsed correctly

Comment: @AmalMurali : I am pretty sure its returning me this : string(22) "14/04/2014 5:13:18 PM " .. If you could please let me know what else you were expecting maybe then i can provide relevant answers - thanks

Comment: Also forgetting the seconds.  Try `'d/m/Y H:i:s A'`

Comment: @Gagan: There you go. You have an extra space at the end of your datetime string. Try this: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', trim($encDateTime));`.

Comment: @user3158900 : when I try that code it gives me False.. :(

Comment: @skrilled UTC is a time zone, not a format.

Comment: Did you try the lower case h, i.e DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', trim($encDateTime)); H signifies a two-digit hour like I said 10 minutes ago. I've already tested and proven this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your date string contains a space at the end - that's why `DateTime::createFromFormat()` fails to parse it. To remove the extra whitespace from the beginning and/or end, you could use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim).

Also, you were originally using `H`, which is the 24-hour format with leading zeroes. In this case, it looks like you have a 12-hour format, so use `g` instead (`h` would work, too).

The following should work:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s A', trim($encDateTime));
```

When you receive such errors, ***always [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) the values***. That way, you can check if the variable contains what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for resolving my question guys - making my dull monday afternoon look good - thanks

Answer (score 7):

The static method `createFromFormat` from DateTime returns `NULL` when there is a parse error. The format that was given (`d/m/Y H:i A`) was wrong. Hence the error  "*Call to a member function `format()` on a non-object*".

You can create DateTime objects from non-standard timestrings like this:

```
$time = '14/04/2014 4:57:16 PM';
$date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s A', $time);
```

The different format characters available and their explanations can be found in [the documentation for `date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the OP's original question?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The Carbon class clearly could not parse the date string. `Failed to parse time string (@14/04/2014 5:03:45 PM ) at position 3 (/): Unexpected character.`

Comment: @AmalMurali - well to be honest actually it does.. I am using carbon date time as I already mentioned in the question. But you were also correct . There was a trailing space and trimming it really helped. If you can post your reply as an answer I will mark that as an answer while I will upvote hannesvdvreken's answer

Comment: I've removed the reference to your answer from mine, as I think mine answers the OP's question without that. I've also rephrased your answer and touched up the formatting slightly - hope you don't mind. Revert if you don't like it :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I noticed you removed the reference.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about Carbon, but this works. You were using a two digit (H) instead of h (edit: g is the same exact thing) in your createFromFormat method:

```
$encDateTime = "14/04/2014 4:57:16 PM";

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', trim($encDateTime));
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

result:

```
2014-04-14 16:57:16
```

Comment: Actually it is wrong. The `h` must be a `g`. I'm sorry.

Comment: Either way, the point was that OP used H which expects a 2 digit hour. Also in my tests this works perfectly fine, so why a g? I've tried every hour in the 24 hour spectrum with no failures.

Comment: Actually, yeah you're wrong - g and h 12-hour format of an hour with or without leading zero 1 through 12 or 01 through 12. g and h are the same thing. (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

Comment: Dude... `14/04/2014 4:57:16`. Where's the leading zero?

Comment: There is no leading zero, aka why you use an h (or g) instead of an H. Stop trying to troll me :p

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), @skrilled. `g` stands for `12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros` and `h` stands for `12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros`. So 4:47:16 is in `g:i:s` format. I'm just being honest.

Comment: You should read documentation yourself @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php - the OP is using CreateFromFormat instead of date, which has different (but very similar) parameters. In this case h and g are the same thing. You are acting like we're using the date method, for whatever reason is oblivious to me. Once again, OP is using CreateFromDate which is in the DateTime library. Had we been talking about the date method you'd be right, but we're not. I'm just being honest.

Comment: @skrilled: All of PHP's Date Time functions use the same format characters as listed in http://php.net/date

Comment: Except this method, which clearly treats h and g as if they were the same exact thing. I linked the documentation for a reason but here once again: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php ;)

Answer (score 0):

just use *laravel* date function as:

```
$productsales=DB::table('tbl_trans')   
     ->leftjoin('tbl_product','tbl_product.prod_id','=','tbl_trans.product_id')  
     ->select(DB::raw('count(product_id) as quant'),'product_id','tbl_product.name','tbl_product.code','tbl_product.price')    
     ->groupBy('product_id','code','name','price')    
     ->whereDate('tbl_trans.created_at','2017-07-29')  
     ->get();


   return view('reports.productsales',compact('productsales'));
```